# XML-TEI How to call two attributes

Tags: xml, tei

I'm working with poetry and I want to give to every verse an own ID that mixes the number of the poem and the number of the verse.

Header:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8" standalone ="no" ?>
    <TEI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
          <titleStmt>
            <title n="013">13</title>
```

Verses:

```
<lg>
    <l n="01"></l>
</lg>
```

I want to create an xml:id attribute for `<l>` like **p013-v01** (poem 13, from n@title; verse 1 from n@l). Is there any way to do it automatically for every single line?

The purpose of this is to compare versions and editions of the same poem. I was told to do this, but to be honest I'm not sure of the utility of this xml:id attribute. I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <xsl:template match="l">
       <xsl:variable name="id-num" select="concat('p', ancestor::TEI/descendant::title/@n, '-v', ./@n)"/>
       <l id="{$id-num}">
          <xsl:attribute name="n"><xsl:value-of select="@n"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </l>
    </xsl:template>
```

The id-value is the result of a concatenation of literal text strings and two attribute values.

Comment: thanks! but you're doing this in the XSLT, right? Would it be possible to do it in the XML file? Nevertheless, your method might for the purpose I described, I guess. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean by doing it in the XML file. Of course, you could edit the XML file manually, but using the XSLT you will get what you want. XSLT is a transformation language that takes an XML file as input and transforms it into a different XML file as output. I just posted the XSLT code and not the XML output it generates.

Comment: I apologise for my lack of expertise. I wasn't able to explain myself better, but now I've understood. You're totally right! Thank you so much :D